# (ArgumentError) could not generate inputs for <association>

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Having some issues with rendering changeset errors on a nested form.

Form rendering:

```
def new(conn, _) do
  changeset = Organizations.Organization.create_organization_changeset(%Organization{workspace: %Workspace{}})
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

The form renders fine initially:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, signup_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>

  <%= text_input f, :name, class: "form-control", required: true, autofocus: true %>
  <%= label f, :organization_name %>
  <%= error_tag f, :name %>

  <%= inputs_for f, :workspace, fn w -> %>
    <%= text_input w, :subdomain, required: true %>
    <%= error_tag w, :subdomain %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Submitting this form calls `create_organization/1`:

```
def create_organization(attrs) do
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.run(:organization, fn(_repo, _result) ->
    changeset = Organization.create_organization_changeset(%Organization{}, attrs)
    tenant = Ecto.Changeset.get_field(changeset, :slug)
    Repo.insert(changeset, prefix: TenantActions.build_prefix(tenant))
  end)
  |> Ecto.Multi.run(:workspace, fn(_repo, %{organization: organization}) ->
    attrs = %{subdomain: attrs["workspace"]["subdomain"}, organization_id: organization.id}

    %Workspace{}
    |> Workspace.changeset(attrs)
    |> put_assoc(:organization, organization)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end)
  |> Repo.transaction()
end
```

The "happy path" works fine. However, if there is a changeset error for `workspace`, for example:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<
  action: :insert,
  changes: %{
    name: "test",
    organization: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :update, changes: %{}, errors: [],
     data: #Organizations.Organization<>, valid?: true>,
    organization_id: 1,
    subdomain: "democompany",
    tenant: "test"
  },
  errors: [
    unique_subdomains: {"That workspace URL is not available.",
     [constraint: :unique, constraint_name: "unique_subdomains"]}
  ],
  data: #Workspaces.Workspace<>,
  valid?: false
>
```

This results in:

```
(ArgumentError) could not generate inputs for :workspace from Workspaces.Workspace. Check the field exists and it is one of embeds_one, embeds_many, has_one, has_many, belongs_to or many_to_many
```

Workspace schema:

```
schema "workspaces" do
  field :subdomain, :string
  belongs_to :organization, Pricetable.Organizations.Organization

  timestamps(type: :utc_datetime_usec)
end
```

Organization schema:

```
schema "organizations" do
  ...
  field :workspace_id, :integer
  has_one :workspace, Workspaces.Workspace
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

```
** (ArgumentError) could not generate inputs for :workspace from Workspaces.Workspace
```

So I assume that you are passing a workspace in `@changeset` and not an organization. Then `inputs_for` tries to get a workspace from a workspace. So I would make sure `@changeset` is actually an organization.

Also, it is a bit awkward use to both multi and `inputs_for`. `inputs_for` is typically used with `cast_assoc/cast_embed`, which sets up the multi internally for you so you don't have to do it manually. More info here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/

Alternatively, you drop the `inputs_for` and work with both changesets separately.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried using `cast_assoc` like in your blog post, but `Organization` and `Workspace` are on different db schemas, so it failed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349799/using-cast-assoc-to-associate-records-on-different-schemas

Comment: What is your Ecto version? If it is Ecto 3.0 and it doesn't work, then I am afraid it won't work, as it assumes all schemas are in the same prefix. So using a Multi instead of `cast_assoc+inputs_for` is indeed the best way to go.